# Best way to updated Git repository after deleting files via ftp

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I had to delete some files from my application via ftp. When I login to Git using command line, and do "git status" , i see the removed files in red.
What do I need to do now to remove those files from the git repository? Basically, saying to Git, "yup, don't want those files anymore".

Git add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.... rather `git rm`, even if you are telling git *after* the fact.

```
git rm file1 file2 file3
git commit -m "Deleting some files"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I didnt realize the "after the fact" part!